# How to use option value in React Select

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-select

*I am learning react and it's fun!*

I am creating a sign up form in React using react-select.

I am mapping values from array:

```
const options = [ 'female', 'male', 'other']
```

```
<Select {...register("gender")} 
          label="Gender"
          fullWidth 
          variant="outlined"
          >
      {options.map(value => (
        <option key={value} value={value}>
          {value}
        </option>
      ))}
      </Select>
```

But I get following warning:

Warning: Use the `defaultValue` or `value` props on  instead of setting `selected` on .

Questions:

1. How do I use the `defaultValue` or `value` props on  ?
2. I am setting label="Gender" but it is not visible, why?

[image: sign up form]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const options = [
  { value: "female", label: "Female" },
  { value: "male", label: "Male" },
  { value: "other", label: "Other" }
];

export default function App() {
  const [gender, setGender] = useState("");

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setGender(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Select
        value={gender}
        onChange={handleChange}
      >
        {options.map((option) => (
          <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.value}>
            {option.label}
          </MenuItem>
        ))}
      </Select>
    </div>
  );
}
```

API reference: https://material-ui.com/api/select/

Working demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-jones-dyfwd?file=/src/App.js:119-788

Comment: Type '{ options: { value: string; label: string; }[]; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & SelectProps'.
  Property 'options' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & SelectProps'.ts(2322)

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-frost-jozz5?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: Thank you for your solution, but I am using material UI library. Select from "@material-ui/core";
Using react-select will mess up my components - different design. I am not sure this issue is solvable with @material-ui/core

Comment: @marialaustsen see my updated answer. Your tag stated react-select, so I assumed you were using that lib. I have changed to material UI solution now.

Comment: Thank you! My mistake for tagging react-select. It works now. I also have an issue with switch material ui according to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67989547/how-to-return-value-state-from-material-ui-switch-using-inputprops